# get innerHTML but input and textarea are all empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with input and textarea fields. 
How can I get the div.innerHTML with the completed fields

```
  var foo = $('#div').innerHTML
```

all fine, but the fields are empty

Comment: You may need to get the value (`.val()`) of each field individually

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML is not a property of jquery object. You need to use text() or val()

Answer (score 1):

See the output in your browser's console of this script. 
Even if there is just one element selected, jquery returns it in a array, so you was calling the property `innerHTML` which obviously a javascript array does not have.

```js
var foo = $('#div').innerHTML;


console.log($('#div'));
console.log($('#div')[0]);
console.log($('#div')[0].innerHTML);
console.log($('#div').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">my div innerHTML</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is Javascript function whicle $('.class') is jQuery

use

```
var foo = $('#id').html(); //for html
var foo = $('#id').text(); //for text and not html tags
```

OR

```
var foo = document.getElelementById('id').innerHTML;
```